# Creating large ndarray from multiple mem-mapped arrays

Tags: numpy

I have multiple large images stored on binary (fits) file on disc. Each array is of the same shape, and dtype.

I need to read in N of these images, but wish to preserve memory-mapping as they would swamp RAM. The easiest way to do this is, of course, read in as elements of a list. However, ideally I would like to treat this as a numpy array ( of shape [n, ny, nx]) e.g. for easy transpose etc.

Is this possible, without reading these in to RAM?

Note: in practice, what I need is more complicated, equivalent to reading in list-of-list (e.g. an M element list, each element itself an N element list, each a ndarray image), but an answer to the simple case above should hopefully be sufficient.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a complex abstraction that creates an array-like interface to multiple files, or you can consolidate your data. The former is going to be fairly complex, and probably not worth your time.

Consolidating the data, e.g. in a [temporary file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile), is a much simpler option, which I've implemented here with the assumption that you are using [`astropy`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/) for your FITS I/O. You can tailor it for other libraries or other use-cases as you see fit.

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from astropy.io import fits

n = 0
with TemporaryFile() as output:
    for filename in my_list_of_files:
        with fits.open(filename) as hdus:
            # If you have a single HDU that you know how to reference, get rid of the loop
            for hdu in hdus:
                if isinstance(hdu, fits.ImageHDU):
                    data = hdu.data.T
                    if n == 0:
                        shape = data.shape
                        dtype = data.dtype
                    elif data.shape != shape or data.dtype != dtype:
                        continue
                    data.tofile(output)
                    n += 1
```

Now you have a single binary flatfile with all your data in row-major order, and all the metadata you need to use numpy's [`memmap`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html):

```
    array = np.memmap(output, dtype, shape=(n,) + shape)
```

Do all your work in the outer `with` block, since `output` will be delete on close in this implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is very close to what I want, but unfortunately the resident memory usage spikes during construction of the TemporaryFile, which means that the RAM will be swamped on construction even if the memory is freed outside your "with" block. Do you have any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: @ChristopherDuncan. The memory spike happens because garbage collection does not delete objects immediately. Let the process run and you should see the gc kick in any time you run out of memory.

Comment: @ChristopherDuncan. Specifically, the line `data = hdu.data.T` decrements the refcount for the previous object that was bound to `data`.